# In VS Code, how can I disable parameter hints? (tooltip/widget that shows function parameter descriptions and overloads)

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm writing a function call and start writing arguments (after typing the opening bracket/parenthesis to the function call), VS Code pops up a large tooltip that shows the function signature and highlights the current parameter I'm writing an argument for. If the function has multiple signatures (overloads), it has buttons to navigate between them. I want to disable this. How can I do that?

It looks like this:
[image: screenshot showing method documentation]

---

I have following settings.json:

```json
"editor.quickSuggestions": false,
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 1000000
```

But this is not doing what I want.

Here is documentation for the [Visual Studio Code IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) where I found the settings above. I use VS Code 1.6.0 on OS X (I experienced it also on previous versions of the editor).

I have all the settings in User Settings `settings.json`. My Workspace Settings `settings.json` is empty.

Comment: Note that "editor.quickSuggestions" is now an object - follow the link above for the latest settings.

Comment: note: If you're interested in the backend side of this stuff, see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#help-with-function-and-method-signatures and https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SignatureHelpProvider.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You turned off code completion correctly. But *parameter hints* are still active. Turn them off by going into the Settings menu, searching for `editor.parameterHints.enabled`, and un-checking the box.

Or put the following entry in your **settings.json**:

```json
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false
```

---

If you ever want to see the parameter hints on-demand, refer to [How to trigger parameter hints in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53731271/4518341). In short, for Windows/Linux, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>; for Mac, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Turn them off with the following entry in your settings.json:

- "editor.hover.enabled": false,

disable the hover function. You will still be able to use CtrlR + K and CtrlR + I as needed.

Comment: This is not a working solution. I've confirmed this. I have the same exact question as the OP - with the same screenshots as I was going to post a question. To get the frustrating `console.log` parameter hints, as shown in screenshot in OPQ, to go away you definitely need `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false`.

Comment: The accepted answer is accurate.

Comment: This is the one I was looking for. Acception solution didnt work.