# How to trigger parameter hints in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to show parameter hints when I position cursor within the parentheses of the calling method.

---

***Note**: I know similar answers already exist for Visual Studio on Reddit, but I couldn't find a quick answer for this question on Stack Overflow. So I've decided to add it.*

Answer (score 413, accepted):

For Windows and Linux:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

For MacOS:

<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: See also [Key Bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_rich)languages-editing]. The command id `editor.action.triggerParameterHints`.

Comment: Keep in mind that in Mac OS `⌘ + Space` may be set up to change the input language. In this case VS Code will not trigger the hints. So you may want to change the key combination either in Mac OS or in VS Code.

Comment: You can also use `ctrl` + `space` to get hints of what parameters you can use.

Comment: Note this conflicts with the Sublime Text Keymap and Settings Importer extension. Go to File > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts, click the "Record keys" button, press Ctrl + Shift + Space, then either right-click & delete the conflicting entry or remap one of them.

Comment: But this is just for JS, not for PHP, like PhpStorm do. There is an excellent extension for it. Check this link out: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MrChetan.phpstorm-parameter-hints-in-vscode

Comment: Does not work for me! I checked the key bindings but nothing happens when I use ctrl shift space

Answer (score 41):

#### Update [v1.6](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_60.md#inlay-hints-for-javascript-and-typescript) - Aug 2021

There's also a new feature called **inlay hints** which you can enable in your `settings.json` like this:

```json
"javascript.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled": "all",
```

Comment: This is now also available for Golang (search for inlay hints in the Go extension settings)

Comment: this is not an answer to this question.

Comment: Toggling inlay hints with your keyboard: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvrIFZYW7eg&ab_channel=Code2020

Comment: @starball Yes / no. It may be almost equally helpful for anyone looking this specific 'stuff' up.

Comment: @LuckyLukeSkywalker sure... but ideally it would go under a question that _actually asks for it_. Maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68698269/11107541) (though it's more general)

Answer (score 17):

### Method1

<kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

[image]

### Method2

**View -> Command Palette->parameter hints**

[image]

### Method3

hover mouse on the function.then it will show the hint.

[image]

If you feel gif is too small click on the gif it will expand.

Comment: Method 3 seems to be Hover (`editor.action.showHover`), which is not exactly the same as Parameter Hints.

Comment: Could you add text to accompany Method 3 please? The gif is pretty small so it's hard to see what you're doing unless you open it in a new tab.

Answer (score 13):

For Java extension, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> works **only** after setting `Java > Signature Help: Enabled` in your `settings.json`:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

1. Code -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Search for "Trigger parameter hints"

   1. Here you can either inspect the defined shortcut
   2. Or you can change keybinding by pressing to the left of "Trigger parameter hints" command name.

Answer (score 9):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to show parameter hints before parentheses, and if you want to trigger parameter hints in parentheses to know about arguments you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: I doubt it. `Ctrl + Space` shows hints when used while cursor is placed over the method name, but not within the parentheses, what is what the op asked for. `Ctrl + Shift + Space` is what he is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

1. command + i -> info parameters
2. commdan + . -> Quick Fix (write const etc.)
3. command + shift + space -> info parameters hints

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If like me you always forget, open the [palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), the shortcut will be displayed:

[image]