# How to trigger destruct hints in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: macos, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

```
const { } = getUser();
```

I remember on Windows os, I used to position the cursor inside the destruct brackets and use ctrl + space or something similar to show the hints for the fields. Then use up/down arrow to select the wanted field. Projects use Typescirpt. Say user object has id and name fields, ctrl + space would show both.

Is there a way to do that on Mac-os? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731271/how-to-trigger-parameter-hints-in-visual-studio-code) solution does not work. Maybe the word is not hint, but rather show fields or something like that. Please correct if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your Trigger Suggest is bound the the right combination

[image]

Comment: hmmm. It had to do something with the fact that I use external, Windows keyboard connected to the Mac. The keybinding was indeed the same as in the screenshot. But when I edited by clicking Ctrl and Space, the Keybinding changed from ^ Space to Ctrl Space.