# Disable Dockerfile POP-UP Assistance in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, dockerfile

Visual Studio Code is my goto-editor for everything that is not a Jetbrains language project. It's useful for Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yml files as well and where these exist outside of IntelliJ projects I use VS Code, its an almost-perfect arrangement.

However, the persistent and frustrating popup trying to tell what the Dockerfile command is that I am editing is incredibly badly designed. It is perfectly positioned to hide the commands above it, which mean you cannot properly create the RUN commands which are generally multi-line. The dialog is continuously hiding the prior commands and this causes the user to lose context. Its like trying to write these questions where you can only see the last character you typed and nothing else. There is a reason why we dont do password dialogs for long passphrases, and this is it.

[image]

How can I get rid of this idiotic thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is handled by the Parameter Hints functionality of VSCode rather than the Docker extension itself.

You can turn these off by unchecking the `Editor › Parameter Hints` setting in your VSCode settings file.

You can still access the hint using the keyboard:

For Linux and Windows:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

For MacOS:

<kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

See also this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53731272).