# Find out python method arguments by vs code

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I installed anaconda on my linux. I am using Vscode to practicing Deep learning.

I installed [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) on vscode to.

I imported like this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I am trying to use `plt.matshow()` but how can I see what are the method arguments by vscode?

Because when I put mouse courser on method, nothing is shown? And none of **alt** or **ctrl** works on **matshow** method !!

[image]

Comment: help(plt.matshow)

Comment: Is there any way to see like popup?@ArthurHarduim

Comment: They appear as soon as you type "("

Comment: When I put (,nothing is shown?@ArthurHarduim

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags you apply before doing so. At least one of them makes no sense at all here!

Answer (score 0):

There as many ways to see the method signature:

1. Using the help builtin:

```py
help(class.method)
```

[image: help builtin output]

2. As soon as you open "(" the signature should appear:
   [image: options appearing after (]
3. Press <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
   [image: Using ctrl+space]

Comment: look https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wg-A3i-94ZRN4fygEdpoLyMEwSiiyDLv/view?usp=sharing , Nothing is opend.

Comment: Strange... Is the Notebook trusted? Are you using the same interpreter of your conda environment?

Comment: As you can see When I installed Anaconda, python 3.8 installed too and I installed python extension as I mentioned above but I don't know why I got this problem @ArthurHarduim

Comment: If you have more then one environment, is possible to choose the interpreter of a specific environment.

Comment: Just (base,conda)and (tf,conda)@ArthurHarduim

Comment: I installed the Pylance extension here and these features stop working. So I guess thats why is not working for you.

Comment: Here is the extension link https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance.  I have also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731271/how-to-trigger-parameter-hints-in-visual-studio-code   Take a look at the Vertex comment.

Comment: In keyboard shortcuts I found `Trigger parameter Hints' is ctrl + shift+ space but unfortunately  not works on my code  https://pasteboard.co/JK63aMa.png @ArthurHarduim

Answer (score 0):

Please try "[Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)", its Jupyter notebook has better "IntelliSense":

[image]

In addition, when I use the Python language service "`Pylance`" in VS Code, there is also "IntelliSense":

[image]