# How can I make Vscode Parameter Hints show directly without enter any character

Tags: visual-studio-code

Trigger Parameter Hints doesn't complete work on my vscode, I follow this question [How to trigger parameter hints in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731271/how-to-trigger-parameter-hints-in-visual-studio-code) but not gonna help.

> Keep in mind that in Mac OS ⌘ + Space may be set up to change the input language. In this case VS Code will not trigger the hints. So you may want to change the key combination either in Mac OS or in VS Code.

Above is also my situation, the default shortcut conflict with Mac, so I change it to [image]

However, it doesn't show the hints only if when I type any character, like this

[image]

What I want is like this, don't need to enter any character, give me all parameter hints directly

[image]

Summary: I want the Hints work directly show all hints that I don't need to enter any character to activate it

Do you have any ideas? Appreciate your help! Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshots show normal IntelliSense suggestions, not parameter hints (parameter hints show the arguments when you are completing a function/method call)

Use `trigger suggest` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>) to show suggestions

Comment: ctrl + space would change the input language which conflict with setting of my mac, that's why I change the keybinding to (shift + command + 9), just change the shortcut, I think it won't affect parameter hints right? But still not working