# How can I toggle inlay hints in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the latest version of VSCode, the default settings have changed and inline parameter hints are always shown in the code despite me not using any setting for it. How do I disable them?

Example (`predicate` and `searchString`):

[image]

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can disable this new default setting by putting this option in your `settings.json` file:

```
"editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off"
```

The full list of available settings are:

- `off`
- `offUnlessPressed`
- `on`
- `onUnlessPressed`

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for this ... but now that I know how to disable this feature, I'm starting to like it.

Comment: I wasted an hour searching for the name of this property. Grateful to you.

Comment: FYI: setting the value to `offUnlessPressed` will let you temporarily show the hints with `CTRL + ALT`

Comment: Omg thanks! I had installed an extension to show me TS types inline.. I uninstalled it, uninstalled VS Code tried everything and it wouldn't work!! This worked, thanks! Was driving me mad

Comment: I've asked for an edit: false = error for me, options: "off" (anwer to question), "offUntilPressed" (interesting), "on", "onUntilPressed"

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestions, I've updated the answer

Comment: The key combination to show the hints when setting "offUnlessPressed" is Ctrl+Alt.
On KDE, this causes the focus to jump to the menu. Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: On macOS, when using `offUnlessPressed`, the key combination to temporarily show hints is `Ctrl + Option`.

Comment: offUnlessPressed, I tried it. I'm just going to set this to "off". If you want to know about the parameters select the method and hit F12, you'll see all the parameter names and their types.

Answer (score 16):

To disable this setting follow these steps :

Step 1: First you need to open 'setting.json'

```
        ( CTRL + SHIFT + P and type "Open Settings (JSON)" and click the 
          matching entry )
```

Step 2: Add this code in 'setting.json'

```
         "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off"
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of editing a JSON file, just do this in the settings UI; Press `ctrl + ,`, type/paste `editor.inlayHints.enabled`, and select the value to want from the drop down

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `editor.inlayHints.enabled` setting. Quoting from the default settings pseudo file:

> ```json
> // Enables the inlay hints in the editor.
> //  - on: Inlay hints are enabled
> //  - onUnlessPressed: Inlay hints are showing by default and hide when holding Ctrl+Alt
> //  - offUnlessPressed: Inlay hints are hidden by default and show when holding Ctrl+Alt
> //  - off: Inlay hints are disabled
> "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "on",
> ```

Note that if you want to control the setting on a per-[language](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) basis, there are at least two options. One option is to wrap the setting in a language block, like so (example with TypeScript):

```json
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off"
}
```

The other option for per-language configuration is to check if the extension you're using which contributes inlay hints for that particular language has any settings for controlling it (see also [the extension API docs for `InlayHintsProvider<T>`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#InlayHintsProvider%3CT%3E)). Several extensions enable you to control enablement at a finer level / toggle inlay hints contributed specifically by that extension. To do that, just search "inlayhints" in your settings.json or settings UI. Here are a couple of examples of such extension-specific settings:

- From [the builtin TypeScript extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/typescript-language-features/package.json): `javascript.inlayHints.*`, `typescript.inlayHints.*`
- From the Python extension: `python.analysis.inlayHints.*`
- From [the Cpptools extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/main/Extension/package.json): `C_Cpp.inlayHints.*`
- From [the Clangd extension](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd/blob/master/package.json): `clangd.inlayHints.toggle`
- From [the Red Hat Java extension](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/blob/master/package.json): `java.inlayHints.*`
- From [the .NET C# extension](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/blob/main/package.json): `csharp.inlayHints.*` and `dotnet.inlayHints.*`
- From [the Rust Analyzer extension](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/blob/master/editors/code/package.json): `rust-analyzer.inlayHints.*`
- At the time of this writing, [the Dart extension](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/blob/master/package.json) does not contribute finer-grained settings for its inlay hints, and changes the default settings for its language mode including `"editor.inlayHints.enabled": "offUnlessPressed"`.
- et cetera.

There are also several other related settings for controlling appearance of inlay hints such as font, and in the colour customizations setting, their colouring and font style. Just search for them in the settings UI or trigger suggestions in settings.json to find them. Or see [{language,extension}-independent VS Code inlay hint customization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77032718/11107541).