# What are these parameter name annotations in my VS Code editor called, and how can I enable/disable them?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to work out the setting that enables these little inline annotations.

[image: screenshot of new vscode insiders annotations]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove inline parameter hints in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698269/how-do-i-remove-inline-parameter-hints-in-vscode)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Those are `Inlay Hints`.  You can enable (the default) or disable them with the setting:

`Editor > Inlay Hints: Enabled`

or change the `Font Family` or `Font Size` by searching for `Inlay Hints` in the Settings UI.

And there is finer control for parameter names/types, variable types and more for js/ts files.

For a lot more, see the release notes [v1.60 release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_60.md#inlay-hints-for-javascript-and-typescript):

> The most significant new tooling feature in TypeScript 4.4 is inlay
> hint support. Inlay hints add additional inline information to source
> code to help you understand what the code does.
>
> Parameter name inlay hints for example show the names of parameters in
> function calls:
>
> [image: parameter inlay hints]
>
> This can help you understand the meaning of each argument at a glance,
> which is especially helpful for functions that take Boolean flags or
> have parameters that are easy to mix up.
>
> To enable parameter name hints, set
> `javascript.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled` or
> `typescript.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled` settings. There are three
> possible values:
>
> - `none` — Disable parameter inlay hints.
> - `literals` — Only show inlay hints for literals (string, number, Boolean).
> - `all` — Show inlay hints for all arguments.
>
> In addition, VS Code also offers inlay hints that show implicit type
> information in your JavaScript and TypeScript code.
>
> Variable type inlay hints show the types of variables that don't have
> an explicit type annotations.
>
> Settings - `javascript.inlayHints.variableTypes.enabled` and
> `typescript.inlayHints.variableTypes.enabled`
>
> [image: variable type inlay hints]

[And more at the release notes link.]

Comment: Also see a vscode team member's explanation of inlay hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946903/vs-code-is-adding-weird-text-to-my-function-calls-in-javascript-and-typescript/68946904?r=SearchResults&s=2|65.6247#68946904

Comment: Important: Even though this answer does mention there are separate JS and TS options I didn't get that far - so it took me way too long to discover I was enabling JS settings instead of TS. I also had to restart VS Code to get any of them to take effect the first time.

Comment: How do we change style of these things? They are way to intrusive and distracting..

Comment: Found it: `"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorInlayHint.background": "red",
        "editorInlayHint.foreground": "black"
    },`

Comment: @vanowm You should write an answer, since your comment is much better than this accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

In additional to the accepted answer, if you want to change the color, it's `editorInlayHint` keys inside of `workbench.colorCustomizations`:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorInlayHint.background": "red",
  "editorInlayHint.foreground": "black"
}
```