# How to turn on feature highlight typescript in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

i saw this, how can I turn this feature on in VS code? I don't know what is it called.
Maybe called hint function...

[What is this called ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DEak.png)

Comment: do you mean intellisense??
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Comment: i installed it, i mean the "message" in picture, how to turn it on?

Comment: you mean suggestion when you type something,
Can you read here please, in order to tell me which feature you are asking about
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946903/vs-code-is-adding-weird-text-to-my-function-calls-in-javascript-and-typescript/68946904?r=SearchResults&s=2|65.6247#68946904

Comment: I got it, thank you guys :)