# How to hide these labels on VS code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

By accidently I got these labels on vs code. How can I remove these labels?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: disable your extensions one by one until it disappears and then find the setting that gives this __code lens__

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68721151/836330

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you for your comment. I tried it but not worked.

Comment: @Mark this is the answer I expected. Thank you.

Comment: I'll close this a s a duplicate then.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to one of the extension features related to reactjs or javascript. Disable the extensions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).