# Viewing function parameters in VSCode

Tags: function, visual-studio-code, parameters, phpstorm, settings

In PhpStorm, we see the expected parameter when using the function. Is this possible with VSCode? I searched but found no answer.

Comment: I suggest you add a screenshot of what you are after (will make life easier to understand what exactly you want). But generally speaking: showing the function parameters is a basic thing (unless I got you wrong).

Comment: I'm sorry. I want to say that the requested parameters are written directly between the parentheses when we write our code. This allows for greater readability and understanding of the code. While I can't find this in VSCode

Comment: So you are after the **Inlay Hints / parameter names**? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/viewing-reference-information.html#inlay-hints If so -- cannot help here in VSCode.

Comment: Exactly ! These are the inlay hints. I found how to enable them in VSCode settings. Just type 'inlay' in the settings and tick the corresponding settings.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68721151/6309), inlay hints are available with [VSCode 1.60](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_60.md#inlay-hints-for-javascript-and-typescript) (for Javascript and Typescript.

This was requested in [`microsoft/language-server-protocol` issue 956](https://github.com/microsoft/language-server-protocol/issues/956) and is not directly supported by LSP yet.

But for the languages (javascript/Typescript) that VSCode currently supports, [VSCode 1.65 (Feb. 2022)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141576) will come with "inlay hint double click gesture", and the setting `vscode.InlayHint.command` to associate a command to said double-click.