# How to disable Inline hints on VSCode? (Java)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I would like to disable this pop-up helper thing on my editor. How do I do that?
There is a weird "next" thing beside my null.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That looks like an inlay hint - in which case try Settings > Editor > inlay Hints. You should see an "Enable/Disable" option. It's enabled by default.

Comment: See potential duplicate [Does anybody know the name of this setting inside of VS Code...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68720113/12567365)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that text is called **Inlay hints** or **Inline hints**. More specifically **inline parameter hints**.

In the case of Java it will be the same as the parameter **'name'** specified in Javadocs for the given function.

As shown below,
[image]

You are seeing this most likely because you have one of **Inline Parameters** plugins installed and enabled.

You need to go to the settings -> **Search inline** -> Extensions - Java -> And set the value to disabled/none.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also disable the inline extension, or uncheck the Java language from the installed extension, like below,
[image]

Once disabled your code should appear without inline parameter hints.

[image]