# How can I hide type display in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I hide this display in vscode. Please reply.
[image]
[image]

I don't know which option controls that display.

Comment: Disable the setting `Editor> Inlay Hints: Enabled`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68721151/836330

Comment: Tnank you Mark.Thanks I solved the problem.