# VSCode + Clangd: type annotations become obtrusive - how to disable?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, language-server-protocol, clangd

I'm using VSCode 1.65.0, the clangd extension, and clangd from latest LLVM (14.0).

It seems to have introduced a feature where it displays type-hints whenever I use `auto`. Here is an example:
[image: clangd type-hints]

This is becoming very obtrusive to me. How can this be turned off? I couldn't find documentation about this feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can go to the command palette (⇧⌘P) and start typing `clangd: Toggle inlay hints` to turn this feature on/off.

Answer (score 18):

In the meanwhile I discovered you can create a file called `.clangd`, and add this:

```
InlayHints:
  Enabled: Yes
  ParameterNames: Yes
  DeducedTypes: No
```

Comment: Using ParameterNames: No means that you will not see annoying parameter adverisement any more (tested) https://github.com/default-writer/c

Comment: As per the documentation https://clangd.llvm.org/config#files you can have per project and also global per user configuration file (`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/clangd/config.yaml`).

Answer (score 3):

`ctrl-shift-p` then input `setting.json` and add this line:

```
"editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off"
```

BTW, it (inlay hints) is a great feature but sometimes it conflicts with some theme (like gruvbox in vscode).

Answer (score 0):

I would have voted to close this as a duplicate of [How can I toggle inlay hints in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68698269/11107541) (toggling inlay hints is done with the `editor.inlayHints.enabled` setting), but there's more useful info that makes this question unique- particularly that the Clangd extension has *its own* setting for toggling inlay hints that *it* contributes. So if you only want to toggle inlay hints contributed by this particular extension, use its setting: `clangd.inlayHints.toggle`.