# Does anyone know how to deactivate this VsCode feature in Java?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[VsCode Java Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCOdq.png)

Does anyone know how I can deactivate this VsCode feature? It is very annoying and I can't figure out how to disable it.

Comment: Search for something called "parameter hints".

Comment: Also check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698269/how-do-i-remove-inline-parameter-hints-in-vscode