# Orange text in VS code when writing in Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, editor

I have recently set up my VS code to be able to run Java. I downloaded the extension pack for java and then downloaded Azul Zulu jdk to run java programs. So far it runs fine, but for certain snippets of code orange blocks of text will appear. They cannot be deleted or modified in any way, and I haven't changed any settings besides changing VS code to use the Zulu jdk as my default jdk.

[Example of the orange blocks I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJS83.png)

I have tried going through my setting related to Java in my VS code, but I can't find anything that would cause this. I haven't done anything besides set up my default jdk and installing the extension for java.

Any help with getting rid of these orange blocks would be appreciated.

Edit:

Java> Inlay Hints > parameter names: Enabled, was the setting that was causing it. Setting this to none fixed the issue. I was confused as the guide I was following did not mention this, nor did it show up on their visual examples when writing code, even though our methods from installing to writing java would have been the same.

Comment: Those seem to just be the name of the parameters to the methods.

Comment: I think this question may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68698269 which appears to have good answers.

Comment: There's also https://devblogs.microsoft.com/java/java-on-visual-studio-code-update-april-2022/ which might be helpful.

Comment: it is a feature added after the tutorial was made

Comment: Hi WaddleDee, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)