# Why does Intellisense add unnecessary details to constructors?

Tags: constructor, intellisense

I'm just switching to VSCode and I've been trying to disable some annoying features with Intellisense. One of my biggest annoyances is shown below, where it keeps telling me what data type the parameters are when constructing a new object.

When I disabled the extension this went away, but I generally like most of the Intellisense features, so I'd like a way to turn off this one particular feature. I keep confusing it for real characters and try to delete them, ending up deleting part of my constructor statement. Note: here I'm trying to remove the `cost:` and `predecessor:` parts that show up.

[image]

Can this be disabled?

### Edit

The source of the issue is Intellisense, as when I disable it the extra text goes away (specifically when I disable the "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" extension which includes Intellisense). Below see another 2 examples of what I have vs what I'm looking for.

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are inlay/inline hints. You can disable them from the settings or settings.json.

[image: What you have]

Search up hints in your settings menu and change the editor.inlayHints.enabled setting to "off" (see the picture below). Alternatively, you can find the Java extension and change the setting from whatever you have (the default is "literals") to "none".

[image]

After that it should be fixed:

[image: Fixed]

Quick note, this looks like a duplicate of [How do I remove inline parameter hints in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698269/how-do-i-remove-inline-parameter-hints-in-vscode)

Comment: If I don't use a picture you can't see the inlay hints and that changing the setting makes them disappear.

Comment: The code itself is also unrelated to the question

Comment: Sorry. That makes sense. Will delete my comment

Comment: dw about it mate. honestly I really wouldve like OP to include (in addition to the photo that shows the problem) some minimal code I could use. that way I wouldn't have had to write my own :) @Caedmon

Answer (score 1):

1. open VS code settings `ctrl+,`
2. paste `java > Inlay Hints > Parameter Names:` in the search bar:
   [image]
3. switch from `literals` to `none`