# How to turn off this suggestion text from VS code when type bracket or comma after type, print or any statement

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, auto, autosuggest

[Please check the text that shows in picture I dont need that message from VS code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPffh.png)

I want to use the suggestions but not that uselesss text over the code. [Its fine that suggestions shows,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgrXd.png)

SOLUTION : Inside - `settings.json` at the top add :

> 

```
{
    "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
    
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "django-html": "html",
        
    },
```

**Mainly This line :** `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,`

If its not exists then add , else if this - `"editor.parameterHints": false,` exists then replace with this - `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,`

THATS ALL.

Comment: Problematic content

Comment: Yes, the (current) last answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698269/how-do-i-remove-inline-parameter-hints-in-vscode shows how to turn on and off the ShowHover setting. Let's not call it useless - you simply don't find it useful, others do find it useful.

Comment: No its not solved

Comment: @scotscotmcc NO

Comment: @scotscotmcc that dup-target is just wrong. inlay hints and parameter hints are completely different things in VS Code.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the VScode settings and in the search bar, type "parameter hints". Look for the setting "Edit in settings.json". In the settings.json file you can then find the "editor.parameterHints.enabled" set it to false, it will look like this:

"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false

you then need to save by pressing ctrl+s, and restart VScode.