# {language,extension}-independent VS Code inlay hint customization

Tags: visual-studio-code, inlay-hints

How can I can customize VS Code inlay hints in ways that are both language-independent and extension-independent?

I want to:

- customize when the inlays appear
- customize their visual style
- adjust these using either [workspace or user settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Motivation: So far, I haven't found brief, to-the-point, one-stop documentation for answering this. Hence this question and my answer below.

Terminological clarification: "Built-in" is not necessarily "language-independent". VS Code does offer some *built-in* settings relating to particular languages; since they are  language-dependent, they are not in-scope  for this question.

Context: I'm using VS Code version 1.81.

Answer (score 1):

Builtin settings (at the time of this writing. see the settings UI or hover tooltips in settings.json for descriptions (though they're pretty self-explanatory)):

- `editor.inlayHints.enabled`
- `editor.inlayHints.padding`
- `editor.inlayHints.fontFamily`
- `editor.inlayHints.fontSize`
- `editor.inlayHints.padding`
- `audioCues.noInlayHints`

Builtin colour customization points (see the `workbench.colorCustomizations` setting):

- `editorInlayHint.background`
- `editorInlayHint.foreground`
- `editorInlayHint.parameterBackground`
- `editorInlayHint.parameterForeground`
- `editorInlayHint.typeBackground`
- `editorInlayHint.typeForeground`

You can find other related settings including those for built-in language extensions by searching "inlay hints" in the settings UI.

Comment: `audioCues.noInlayHints` piqued my curiosity: here's a ~2 minute no fluff video illustrating VS Code audio cues: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzDnpvjNcdQ

Answer (score 0):

### Customization

Here is a summary of the relevant `settings.json` options for VS Code, as of version 1.81.1 :

```json
// options are: "on", "onUnlessPressed", "off", "offUnlessPressed"
"editor.inlayHints.enabled": "...",
 
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  // specify the theme you want to customize; e.g. Dark Modern
  "[Dark Modern]": {
    "editorInlayHint.foreground": "...",
    "editorInlayHint.background": "...",
    "editorInlayHint.typeForeground": "...",
    "editorInlayHint.typeBackground": "...",
    "editorInlayHint.parameterForeground": "...",
    "editorInlayHint.parameterBackground": "...",
  }
}
```

### Resources

- [VS Code API reference docs: theme colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color)
- [VS Code issue #133673: customize inlay colors](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133673)
- [Rust Subreddit: changing inlay hint color](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/uki3xp/changing_inlay_hint_color_in_vscode/)