# how i can disable this caption in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntg0N.png)
as 'searchElement:'

can't find some in settings, I need the rest of the settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n7Nw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUTbO.png)
like this "message" and "...optionalParams"
please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I toggle inlay hints in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698269/how-can-i-toggle-inlay-hints-in-vs-code)

Comment: Yes, thank you!