# How to Remove Unwanted Suggestions in VS Code with Specific Extensions Installed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm currently using Visual Studio Code with the following extensions installed: .NET Install Tool, C#, C# Dev Kit, MSBuild Project Tools, and C# Extensions. I've noticed that I keep receiving suggestions which are making my code messy and unreadable. Even when I try to disable the C# Extensions, these suggestions persist.

Here is an example of the suggestions that appear:

https://ibb.co/84ZZTRy

https://ibb.co/LkJFzFp

These suggestions weren’t showing up a week ago, but now they’ve suddenly started appearing.

Even when I deactivate all extensions except for the ones necessary for C# development (C#, .NET Install Tool, C# Dev Kit), the suggestions continue to show up. I'm curious if these suggestions are originating from any of these three extensions.

Comment: They're called inlay hints. Have a look at `csharp.inlayhints` articles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I toggle inlay hints in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698269/how-can-i-toggle-inlay-hints-in-vs-code) It's not a c#-specific question, but the answers do talk about inlay hints in general.

Comment: Not me, but I know some people don't like screenshots of code (not indexable), but it's perfectly valid in this case ‍♀️