# How to disable these highlighted indications in java vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I Actually want to delete these highlighted hints shown here after installing java extension pack in vscode please check out the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOcww.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69148254/9938317

Answer (score -1):

The most significant new tooling feature in TypeScript 4.4 is inlay hint support. Inlay hints add additional inline information to source code to help you understand what the code does.

To enable parameter name hints, set `javascript.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled` or `typescript.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled` settings. There are three possible values:

1. none - Disable parameter inlay hints.
2. literals - Only show inlay hints for literals (string, number,
   Boolean).
3. all - Show inlay hints for all arguments.

You can refer to the [update log](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_60.md#inlay-hints-for-javascript-and-typescript) for more details

Comment: this question was about java...