# Is there a way to remove suggestions in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am doing some mobile app development using React JS. When I try to add styling to the app a rather annoying block follows my text cursor.

Is there a way to remove this in the VS settings or in my code some way?

[image]

Comment: press `Esc` to get it gone

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you want by disabling *parameter hints*, you can turn them off by going into the Settings menu, searching for `editor.parameterHints.enabled`, and un-checking the box.

Or put the following entry in your **settings.json**:

```json
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false
```

---

If you ever want to see the parameter hints on-demand, refer to [How to trigger parameter hints in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53731271/4518341). In short, for Windows/Linux, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>; for Mac, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.