# VS Code parameter hint for a specific parameter

Tags: visual-studio-code

[How to trigger parameter hints in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731271/how-to-trigger-parameter-hints-in-visual-studio-code) is not sufficient for me. I have a generated function that accepts 300 or so parameters for an 20 paramter object (and for each paramter you have greaterThanOrEquals, lessThanOrEquals, Equals, contains, ... parameters generated, and right at the end page size, sorting, distinct).
Now I have the problem that I don't know where I have to put my sorting parameter exactly.

Using ctrl-shift-space shows me the 300 paramter names, but I still don't know which parameter is under my cursor.
I'd love to have it like Intellij does it: A hint next to the parameter name so it looks like it were named parameters. VS Code doesn't... Is there any way? Any plugin or something, I could use?

The plugin I'm using right now is `volar` for `vue` js framework.

Comment: that screams for a redesign with a configuration object, or arrays, I'm curious what the function does?

Comment: it all depends on the language extension you use

Comment: I editedt the question - hopefully it's a bit clearer now.  I don't have control over the generated function, it'll always have these many parameters.  It's a jhipster based API call, and I generate the api calling, so it's just how it is, I guess.

Comment: can you give the commands used to generate that code, I'm curious about the generated code of that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSC has a setting for that but it is off by default.

In the settings GUI search for: `inlay hints`

For function parameters change the setting:

**Javascript > Inlay Hints > Parameter Names: Enabled**

`javascript.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled`

set it to `all` or `literal`

You can check the other `inlay hints` settings too.

Comment: I saw this, and it works, but the feature is not very well implemented (not complaining, it made me overlook the feature in the first place).
Pressing "," and deleting it again, made the popup appear.

Comment: @Frischling I'm still interested in what tool generated that function

Comment: https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-axios from an .yaml file that was generated by khipster, for a service that receives a DataTransferObject with ~15 attributes.  The spring-boot criteria api makes tons of possibilities for each of the object's parameters, resulting in a freakishly huge function.

Comment: @Frischling thanks, something to read this weekend