# How do I remove this popup in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: VSCode output]

This is related to tools used for programming: how do I remove this thing that shows up in Visual Studio Code when I write any syntax? (Please ignore the code: I just started two days ago.)

Comment: later you will like this feature when you use some large modules, just press escape when you want it to go away

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to turn off code suggestions in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972256/unable-to-turn-off-code-suggestions-in-visual-studio-code)