# VS Code - Parameter Hints is disabled, but popup is still shown

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am seeing the below popup in Visual Studio Code. It is being automatically shown as I type.

[image: VS Code Popup]

I thought that this popup would not be automatically shown if I disabled the option "Editor > Parameter Hints", but apparently this is not the case.

The language is of course Python.

While the parameter hints are sometimes useful, I would like to be able to trigger them using keyboard shortcut of choice rather than having them automatically appear and "steal" keystrokes.

Comment: those aren't parameter hints (for which see https://stackoverflow.com/q/39972256/11107541). that's the suggestions widget. commonly mixed up for beginners. this might be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32911977/11107541

Comment: @starball Thanks, that's useful info. I have already set "editor > suggest on trigger characters" to off

Comment: my point is that you want to disable suggestions. please read ALL the answer posts there. in particular, xyz's answer.

Comment: @starball I don't want to disable them necessarily, just stop the popup from automatically showing...

Comment: ... then you probably want to disable quickSuggestions, which is _also_ mentioned in several of the answer posts there.