# How do I get rid of suggestion box in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

New to programming and using VS code to program a python game and I constantly get suggestions that are distracting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyWnI.png)

Tried disabling everything in settings but still getting these suggestions.

Also - how useful are these suggestions?

I have never worked professionally so unsure if its something I should get used to compared to just disabling it

Comment: You probably have a linting enabled through an extension (such as the Python extension or the Flake8 extension). These suggestions are worth following as they ensure unified coding styles across your project. Can you maybe share an example of a suggestion that you are getting to confirm if you have a linter?

Comment: Yep I've got Pylance enabled.

Comment: Yeah not too sure why my photo wasn't loading. 

I've updated it now, it is a big suggestion box that appears on my screen with code.

Comment: maybe now it bothers you but when you know more of the Python library you don't remember all the parameters and in what order or type, Just press `Esc` or keep typing.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39972256/11107541

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the Pylance extension installed, the "suggestions" are provided by it. Pylance has multiple settings that causes these suggestions (one of them being linting). I don't recommend uninstalling this extension to simply disable the suggestions because Pylance also provides other useful features.

For example, if you want to disable linting, add the following to your `.vscode/settings.json` file:

```json
"python.analysis.ignore": [
        "*"
    ]
```

If you want to disable other kinds of suggestions, you should take a look at the [official Python Language Settings for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_python-language-server-settings) and disable the specific setting for your case.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me but thanks anyway dude.

Turns out it was something called 'Type Checking' and I was able to disable it by switching "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions":  to false.

Comment: The suggestions that you were seeing were not due to linting then. You can disable more of these suggestions by taking a look at the [different settings available](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_python-language-server-settings) for Pylance.